# Sha256 hash generated from Java differs from OpenSSL and Sha256Sum utilities. Why?

Tags: java, apache, openssl, guava, sha256

Here is a java code that generates a sha256 hash for a string in java.

```
public static void main(){

    String data = "hello world";

    // Generate the Sha256 hash using Apache Common Codec library
    String hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex( data);

    System.out.println("Apache : Sha256hash: "+ hash);

    // Generate Sha 256 hash by using guava library
    final String hashed = Hashing.sha256()
            .hashString(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .toString();


    System.out.println("Guava  : Sha256hash: "+ hashed);
}
```

When I run the program I get the following values. Both hashes are exactly same.

```
Apache : Sha256hash: b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
Guava  : Sha256hash: b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
```

Now, I generated the Sha256 hash for the string "hello world" from command line.

**command line util sha2**

```
echo "hello world" | sha2 -256
SHA-256 ((null)) = a948904f2f0f479b8f8197694b30184b0d2ed1c1cd2a1ec0fb85d299a192a447
```

**OpenSSL util**

```
echo 'hello world' | openssl dgst -sha256
a948904f2f0f479b8f8197694b30184b0d2ed1c1cd2a1ec0fb85d299a192a447
```

As you see from these examples, the values generated from Command line differ from values generated from Java ( Apache and Guava )

The input string is same, but the hashes are different. Why this difference happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I literally had a revision to this answer recently.

The issue is echo adds a newline to your data. If you used `echo -n` or `openssl dgst -sha256 <<< 'hello world'` you'd get the right value.

See [OpenSSL create SHA hash from shell stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066171/openssl-create-sha-hash-from-shell-stdin/11066190#11066190)